# 8 rows to columns with blanks VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Please suggest a code:
I need to convert 8 rows into a single column. An example is shown below. I want to keep all blank cells. I always need to incorporate 8 rows, even though, some of the cells may be blank(example below). I could have up to 6 columns of data.
 Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

This:

```
columnA  columnB   columnC
AAAA     BBBB      CCCC
AAAA     BBBB      CCCC
AAAA     BBBB      CCCC    
AAAA     blank     blank
AAAA     blank     blank
AAAA     blank     blank
blank    blank     blank
blank    blank     blank
```

To this:

```
columnA

AAAA
AAAA
AAAA
AAAA
AAAA
AAAA
blank
blank
BBBB
BBBB
BBBB
blank
blank
blank
blank
blank
CCCC
CCCC
CCCC
blank
blank
blank
blank
blank
```

Comment: There is an Excel worksheet TRANSPOSE function, which converts rows into columns. This may help: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/transpose-function-HP010069834.aspx Rgds,

Comment: Hi, did my answer below help? That seems to accomplish what you're looking for. Tks

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you are looking for

```
Sub test()
Dim startRow As Integer
Dim startColumn As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim LastColumn As Integer
Dim actRow As Integer
Dim actColumn As Integer
Dim targetRow As Integer

startRow = 1   
startColumn = 1
LastRow = 8
LastColumn = 6
targetRow = LastRow + 1

For actColumn = startColumn + 1 To LastColumn
    For actRow = startRow To LastRow
        With ActiveSheet
            .Cells(targetRow, 1) = .Cells(actRow, actColumn)
            .Cells(actRow, actColumn).Clear
        End With
        targetRow = targetRow + 1
    Next actRow
Next actColumn

End Sub
```

You can improve the code for example replacing the `ActiveSheet` statement by using `Sheets("sheetname")` instead

Answer (score 0):

The following code is very general and can be modified as needed for your UI.

The logic is as follows:

1. Copy the range into memory
2. Rearrange the contents as required into a one-dimensional string array
3. Join the elements of the array delimited by a Newline character (CRLF for Windows)
4. Copy this joined string into the system clipboard

Hence, you can highlight the range you want re-arranged and run the macro via some button on the spreadsheet or through a button in the Ribbon and the required output is put into the clipboard.

Then you can simply paste it wherever you need to use it.

```
    Sub CopyToClipboard()
        Dim Clipboard As New MSForms.DataObject
        ' Create Clipboard data object

        Dim CopiedArray As Variant
        CopiedArray = Selection
        ' Randomly sized range copied

        Dim nRows As Long, nCols As Long
        nRows = UBound(CopiedArray, 1)
        nCols = UBound(CopiedArray, 2)

        Dim OutputStr() As String
        ReDim OutputStr(1 To nRows * nCols)
        ' Create a uni dimensional string array for output

        Dim i As Long, j As Long
        For j = 1 To nCols
            For i = 1 To nRows
                OutputStr((j - 1) * nRows + i) = CopiedArray(i, j)
            Next i
        Next j

        Clipboard.SetText Join(OutputStr, vbCrLf)
        ' The string array is joined with the
        ' Carriage Return + LineFeed (CRSF) delimiter


        Clipboard.PutInClipboard
        ' Contents of the Clipboard object are
        ' copied to the system clipboard

        Set Clipboard = Nothing
        ' Destroy clipboard object
    End Sub
```